# How would you position a HTML element while having animations running

Tags: html, css, animation

I have CSS animations running on an HTML element but I am unable to position the HTML element freely on the HTML page so, how would I do this?

I have tried using doing this in order to position the HTML element freely on the page.

```
<div style="text-align: center;"><p class="animated flipInX">2</p></div>
```

But it does not work.

```css
/* GLOBAL STYLES */
    body {
      background: #011;
      padding-top: 5em;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    /* DEMO-SPECIFIC STYLES */
    .typewriter h1 {
      color: #fff;
      font-family: Consolas,monaco,monospace;
      overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
      border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
      white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
      margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
      letter-spacing: .15em; /* Adjust as needed */
      animation:
        typing 3.5s steps(30, end),
        blink-caret .5s step-end infinite;
    }
    
    /* The typing effect */
    @keyframes typing {
      from { width: 0 }
      to { width: 100% }
    }
    
    /* The typewriter cursor effect */
    @keyframes blink-caret {
      from, to { border-color: transparent }
      50% { border-color: white }
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <div class="typewriter">
      <h1>1</h1>
    </div>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css">
      <p class="animated flipInX">2</p>
    </head>
    </html>
```

Comment: `class="text-align: center;"` is not valid. class is a className = string which you then use to select that element. What you need is `style = " text-align: center" ` . Didn't look at the rest of the code

Comment: did you mean style="text-align:center" ??

Comment: what you mean by *position the HTML element freely on the page*?

Comment: What should be the expected output ? read more about [position in CSS](https://dzone.com/articles/css-position-relative-vs-position-absolute) to get some idea.

Comment: Solution might be to use css `position`but am not sure what you mean by position HTML freely.

Comment: @mw509 With position the HTML element freely I mean that I am able to put the element anywhere on the page but still run the animation (in this case flipInX)

Comment: @jr123456jr987654321 I posted an answer. I hope it helps. Let me know

Comment: Did you mean to center the elem on page?

Answer (score 1):

To position things anywhere on the screen, likely means you also want to be able to use any part of the screen even if there were items all over the page. Best way to do this is to use the position css property. so on whatever you want to move around, write a css class or id to it like this;

```
position: absolute; 
z-index: 1;
top: 0px;
left: 200px;
```

Here is a link I played with the example you gave. https://jsfiddle.net/cphutx78/

Let me know if it hel

Comment: Is it possible to do that and still have the animation run

Comment: Well do you know for the number 2, it is not working for that is there a way for that too. Thanks.

Comment: from the code, `typewriter` is what triggers the typewriter animation. However, there is an `h1` tag to it which means it will only work when there is an h1 present. To remove that restriction, you need to remove the `h1` from the css class. then now anywhere you apply `class="typewriter"` in the HTML will have the animation

Comment: Sorry I meant the "flipInX" animation which should be able to be moved anywhere and still run the animation

Comment: yes. it should work still. These links might help a bit 
https://jsfiddle.net/cphutx78/
https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/